# OneSignal: Create segment via API?

Tags: onesignal

is it possible to create a Segments or app interests by the API other than by the OneSignal console? I need to create from an app manager

Answer (score 0):

According to their github, Unfortunately OneSignal does not have this feature at the moment:: 
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/272

> There are no limits on the number of filters you may add to a segment
>   or the number of segments you may create in OneSignal. **Segments may
>   only be created from the Dashboard, but segments may be referenced
>   from the SDK and API.**